# Join two lists and select nested items with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of the following class:

```
public class SiloRelationship
{
    public int RelationshipType { get; set; }
    public string MasterKey { get; set; }
    public string SlaveKey { get; set; }
    public int QueryId { get; set; }
}
```

I have a second list of the following class:

```
public class SiloNode
{
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public string Url { get; private set; }

    public List<NodeQuery> Queries { get; private set; }
}
```

Which has a sub-class:

```
public class NodeQuery
{
    public string Query { get; private set; }
    public int Seq { get; private set; }
}
```

Lists:

- LandingSilo.Relationships is a list of SiloRelationship
- LandingSilo.Nodes is a list of SiloNode.

Here's my query - there is a simple join, after which I need to return the Url and Query properties - the filter should result in a single QueryNode from the list.

What we have is:

```
SiloRelationship => 1 to 1 SiloNode => 1 to many QueryNode
```

A Kvp would be adequate for the purpose of the exercise but I can't see the Query property with the code I've got so far.

```
var query =
    from r in LandingSilo.Relationships
    join n in LandingSilo.Nodes on r.SlaveKey equals n.Key
    where r.RelationshipType == 1 &&
    n.Queries.Select(y => y.Seq).Contains(r.QueryId)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: In your query you have `LandingSilo.Nodes` instead of `LandingSilo.SiloNode`, I don't know if that's an actual mistake or just a mistake when you copied the code here

Comment: No it isn't a mistake Pietro, just unclear. SiloNode is a class - the two static lists I'm marrying together are LandingSilo.Relationships and LandingSilo.Nodes.

Comment: I don't see how it would result in a single `NodeQuery`. Won't it give you at most as many `NodeQuery`s as there are `SiloRelationship`s of type `1`?

Comment: The query is incomplete as I'm struggling to get to the properties I need. Simply put, SiloRelationships could contain a number of rows after filtering but I only want to fetch the single matching row NodeQuery.Query where Seq == QueryId

Comment: Yes, but there are multiple relationships and multiple nodes. So if you have two relationships with `QueryId` `1` and `2`, and then two different nodes that have a query with `Seq` equal to `1` and the other to `2` you're gonna get one query for each relationship -- amounting to two total queries.

Comment: @V0ldek Sorry but I don't quite understand.

Comment: How do I move the discussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178369/discussion-between-v0ldek-and-john-ohara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<string> queries = LandingSilo.Relationships
    .Where(r => r.RelationshipType == 1)
    .Join(
        LandingSilo.Nodes, 
        r => r.SlaveKey, 
        n => n.Key, 
        (r, n) => n.Queries.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Seq == r.QueryId))
    .Where(q => q != null)
    .Select(q => q.Query);
```

Line by line: filter all `Relationship`s with type different from `1`, join on `SlaveKey`/`Key` and select the only query in the node that has the `Seq` equal to the `Relationship`s `QueryId`. Filter out `null` results and select the `Query` property. This is going to throw an `InvalidOperationException` if there are multiple queries within one node matching.

This can be also done in the LINQ keyword syntax like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> queries = 
    from r in LandingSilo.Relationships
    where r.RelationshipType == 1
    join n in LandingSilo.Nodes on r.SlaveKey equals n.Key
    from q in n.Queries.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Seq == r.QueryId)
    where q != null
    select q.Query;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to filter the `Queries`. Change last statement like below

```
select n.Queries.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Seq == q.QueryId);
```